# File in repository after clone, but no history

Tags: mercurial, history

We have a Mercurial repository converted from Subversion a while ago and have today noticed that there are files in the repository that have *no* history whatsoever.

One of the sympomts of this behaviour is that hg status reports the file as clean, while hg log reports no changesets for the same file:

```
> hg clone [repo]
> hg st -c FileWithMissingHistory.cs

C  FileWithMissingHistory.cs

> hg blame FileWithMissingHistory.cs
FileWithMissingHistory.cs: no such file in rev [...]
> hg log FileWithMissingHistory.cs
> hg log FileWithMissingHistory.cs -f
abort: cannot follow nonexistent file: "FileWithMissingHistory.cs"

> hg log -v | grep FileWithMissingHistory.cs

[gives output, there arechangesets mentioning the file]
```

Obviously the filenames have been changed in the example. I've tried using hg verify, but this command reports that the repo is fine. Has anyone experienced this and is there anything we could do to bring the history "back to life"? Placing dummy history on the files in question would be acceptable, but suboptimal.

**EDIT:**
I've done some more investigation and noticed that "FileWithMissingHistory.cs" was renamed from another filename (hg copy + delete) in revision 238. If I do hg update -r238 and hg log on the file at this revision I do not get any history. Doing hg log on the original file reports the history as expected, so it seems that the history is somehow lost during copy (again, the file is renamed using hg copy, and the changeset clearly indicates that the file has been copied).

Comment: What's the output of the following commands? `hg version`, `hg identify`, `hg summary`, and `hg verify`? And does `hg manifest` list the file?

Comment: hg version=1.7.3, hg identify prints current changeset id (nothing else), hg summary prints the commit w/message and the parent (one parent only). hg manifest lists the file in question.

Comment: Do you remember which version of Mercurial you used to convert the repo? If not, did you use the latest version at that time, and if so, do you remember when you did it?

Comment: @lasse: We used the latest version (TortoiseHg) at the time, beginning of January. From https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/ReleaseNotes#tortoisehg-119 it seems that the HG version was 1.7.3 when we did the conversion as well.

Comment: @larsm Did you do clones on a SMB share? Does the cloning work when there are different drives involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally tracked down the cause of the effects mentioned above and it seems that this is caused by mixed casing issues. Some of the files are located in directories with lowercase names while others are located in the directories with equal names, only that the case is mixed (e.g. "directory/FileWithHistory.cs" and "DiReCtOrY/FileWithMissingHistory.cs"). On Windows, both files will be located in the same directory causing issues.

Comment: I had a similar issue where my .hgignore file had a pattern in it that was causing hg to ignore a few of my project files that had the word 'settings' in them.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds strange, actually impossible. What I would try to debug this issue is to update to different revisions and check at which revision the file appears in the working copy the first time. If you do this in a binary search fashion (similar to how the [bisect extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BisectExtension) works), you should find a revision which introduces the file after a few updates.

This does not solve the problem, but it may help in tracking down its source.